# Why jackson is serializing transient member also?

Tags: json, jackson, transient

I am serializing a POJO into JSON using Jackson 2.1.4 but I want to ignore a particular field from getting serialized. I used transient but still it is serializing that element.

```
public class TestElement {

    int x;

    private transient String y;

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public String getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(String y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

I am serializing as following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    TestElement testElement = new TestElement();
    testElement.setX(10);
    testElement.setY("adasd");
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    String serialized = om.writeValueAsString(testElement);
    System.err.println(serialized);
}
```

Please don't suggest `@JsonIgnore` as I don't want to tie my model to jackson specific annotations. Can it be done using transient only? Is there any API on objectmapper for visibility settings?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The reason Jackson serializes the `transient` member is because the getters are used to determine what to serialize, not the member itself - and since `y` has a public getter, that gets serialized.
If you want to change that default and have Jackson use fields - simply do:

```
om.setVisibilityChecker(
  om.getSerializationConfig()
    .getDefaultVisibilityChecker()
    .withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
    .withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
);
```

Another way to ignore a property on serialization is to do it directly on the class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "y" })
public class TestElement {
...
```

And another way is directly on the field:

```
public class TestElement {

    @JsonIgnore
    private String y;
...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I'd prefer a way in which I don't have to tie my model to jackson specific annotations. One thing i can't understand is why jackson is serializing even transient member? Other API's like Smart JSON or even java serializer don't do that. Any idea about this?

Comment: I updated my original answer to explain the problem further and provide you with a solution - hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, i was looking for first solution. Now I can do this without having to use all the jackson specific annotations.

Comment: No worries - there are actually a few additional ways of doing this - you can check out my post on ignoring certain fields here: http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-properties-on-serialization - glad I could help. Cheers.

Comment: Here's an alternative way (suggested as an edit) to do it: ```om.disable(MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_GETTERS)
om.disable(MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_IS_GETTERS)
om.enable(MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_FIELDS)```

Comment: So if I didn't miss something here, there's no way to get it to simply respect the transient keyword? (Which you'd imagine it would do automatically.) Yeah that sounds incredibly dumb.

Comment: Wouldn't this break compatibility with existing code using the getters and setters?

Answer (score 47):

A new way to stop Jackson from serializing and deserializing is to call `mapper.configure(MapperFeature.PROPAGATE_TRANSIENT_MARKER, true)`.

Comment: This is confirmed to work with Kotlin's @Transient annotation on Kotlin version 1.2.71.

Comment: This method is deprecated now - use:
`JsonMapper.builder().configure(MapperFeature.PROPAGATE_TRANSIENT_MARKER, true)`

Answer (score 9):

You can configure it with springs properties

```
spring.jackson.mapper.propagate-transient-marker=true
```

Answer (score 4):

I can't make comments so complete the previous response here, changing the (now) deprecated method `setVisibilityChecker` and adding a missing clause for booleans:

```
mapper.setVisibility(
    mapper.getSerializationConfig().
    getDefaultVisibilityChecker().
    withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY).
    withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE).
    withIsGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
);
```