# Springboot JPA entity is auto loading lazy join entities

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity as

```
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "feature")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    public class Feature {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Integer id;

        @Column(name = "name")
        private String name;

        @Column(name = "description")
        private String description;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "featureId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private transient Collection<FeatureComponent> components;
}
```

While in its Repository(Dao) file, I have

```
public interface FeatureDao extends JpaRepository<Feature, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT e FROM Feature e")
    public List<Feature> getAll();

    @Query("SELECT e FROM Feature e LEFT JOIN e.components fc WHERE e.id= :id")
    public Feature getWithDetail(@Param("id") Integer id);
}
```

When I'm calling **featureDao.getAll();** it returns all features but including **components** list filled and because of that, my response it being too large to load on client-side.

I'm unable to understand why it is happening when I'm using **Lazy** fetch mode and didn't mentioned joining with **components** in my **getAll** method.

Please help to resolve that issue,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use `findAll()` of `JpaRepository`?

Comment: @Mansoor, Actually I have to add a where clause with a sub query... to avoid complexity in question, I skipped that part...

Comment: My guess would be https://stackoverflow.com/a/21749892/1225328, i.e. Jackson triggering the unwanted queries to `FeatureComponent` when seralising your `List<Feature>` since it finds a getter for `components`.

Comment: But I don't want to avoid that 'components' because I need them for other purposes (that you can check in my other query i.e. getWithDetail)... I Know, We can easily ignore entity fields by @JsonIgnore annotation...

Answer (score 1):

Just like @spOOm already mentioned I also suspect this is the side effect of Jackson `Feature` entity serialization into JSON triggering the load of all the `components`.

That is why using DTOs instead of plain Entities is usually advisable when returning data via a Controller. With DTOs, you clearly define whatever you want to include in the response to the caller. You can even reorganize your model so that it fits better the needs of the clients. You decouple your inner model and the model your API consumers know, making it possible to rework your inner model and still keep the same public model. You could have the following DTO.

```java
public class FeatureSimpleDto {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
}
```

Then, in your Controller or Service (here you can find different opinions) you would basically convert your `Feature` entity into a `FeatureSimpleDto` that would be returned by your Controller. Here you can use mapping libraries such as [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/) or you can do it on your own (I usually tend to prefer doing it on my own, one less dependency to rely on).

Answer (score 0):

Using Lombok may be a problem, depending on the relationship between tables, try to create getters manually in entity classes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for providing workarounds... But every work item requires lots of changes which were not possible for me...

Luckily I found a solution that is working fine for me... Better to post here...

**Step-1: Add dependency in pom.xml file**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate5</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**Step-2: Add a 'Bean' for Hibernate Module**

We can add bean in any file having **@Configuration** annotation... Even, we can add in Springboot main application file(where we have **main** method).

```
@Bean
public Module datatypeHibernateModule() {
    return new Hibernate5Module();
}
```

That's it, **Happy Coding...**